# jQuery .html() method works inside (document).ready but not outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into a rather bizarre problem here where the .html() method works inside (document).ready, writing a textbox to .anchor1, whereas outside (document).ready, the .html() methods that attempt to write "c" and "d" to .anchor2 (the near-equivalent of anchor 1) don't do anything. "a" is being logged to the console, despite the fact that this is in the same "if" statement as the line, "$(".anchor2").html("c");". Why is this happening?

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="anchor1">y</div>
<div class="anchor2">z</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".anchor1").html("<textarea></textarea>");

    $('#menu1').on("menuselect", function (event, ui) {
        var value1 = $("#menu1 option:selected").text();
        var value2 = $("#menu2 option:selected").text();
    });
    hourly1 = $(".amount").val()
});

value1 = "weekly earnings";
value2 = "annual salary";

function switch1() {
    value1 = $("#menu1 option:selected").text();;
}

function switch2() {
    value2 = $("#menu2 option:selected").text();
}
$(".anchor2").html("d");
if (((value1 == "weekly earnings") && (value2 == "annual salary")) || ((value2 == "weekly earnings") && (value1 == "annual salary"))) {
    $(".anchor2").html("c");
    console.log("a");
}
```

Comment: Nothing bizarre here. You cannot manipulate DOM before it's loaded.

Comment: Remove one semicolon(;) from switch1 function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because of when your JavaScript is executing your ".anchor2"  div is not rendered in DOM.
$(document).ready makes sure that your DOM is ready and then execute the code written in callback.
if you don't want to use $(document).ready move all of you js to bottom of the page.

i.e just before the ending `"</body>"` tag.
In this case your HTML is rendered and $(".anchor2").html("d"); code find the .anchor2 div in DOM. Hence able to add innerHTML to your div.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: If you place your js code after </body> or after </html> then still it works. Why? I don't know.

Comment: @RNKushwaha Ya that will also work in modern browsers but this will make your HTML invalid.

Comment: I suppose I'll just put everything inside $(document).ready. I didn't realize the DOM wasn't loaded outside that function.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("a");` is working since it has nothing to do specifically with jQuery. It works in normal JavaScript as well.

You should either write your code related to `$(".anchor2")` inside `$(document).ready()` or write code in JavaScript instead of jQuery e.g.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("anchor2")[0].innerHTML = 'c'; //whatever you want
```